# Camera starts at floor level 2019.2 + MRTK v2.0.0

Tags: mrtk

For some reason everytime I load the scene on my Hololens 1 the camera starts at floor level and the scene content doesn't appear to anchor to the floor in the real world..

Using the MRTK demo project files I've created a scene and added in the MRTK packages, configured spatial perception in the player settings, turned on the spatial awareness settings, set to room scale, added observers (checked they're working), added the spatial collider and renderer to an empty game object, and scratched my head many times..

Anyone know what I'm missing/doing wrong?

Unity editor screenshot:
[image: Editor]

Comment: you camera is on (0,0,0) and your floor is at the same position...I cant look up right now but isnt it mentioned somewhere in the documentation that you should move your scene-stuff except the camera to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On HoloLens (1st gen and 2) the origin of the world is at the head. From the image you posted, it appears you are designing a VR style scene. In VR, the origin is generally the floor.

As @Perazim mentions, for VR style scenes on HoloLens, you will want to adjust the content placement to account for the origin being at the head. In the Mixed Reality Toolkit example scenes (ex: Demos\HandTracking\Scenes\HandInteractionExamples) the content is contained within a SceneContent object to facilitate easy adjustment.

The older, HoloToolkit contained a [script](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/htk_development/Assets/HoloToolkit/Boundary/Scripts/SceneContentAdjuster.cs) that may come in handy in your scenario. While we have not yet ported it to MRTK v2.x, it should be reasonably straight forward to update.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Many thanks. In the end we implemented Azure spatial anchors in to the MRTK project and now we can tap the floor to place the scene content (all contained within a prefab) which resolves the floor/camera issue. Problem solved, and now we can go ahead and look at persistence between devices/sessions and eventually multiplayer interactions.